# ip-tools vs old ifconfig

Tags: linux, centos, command-line, network-interface, networkmanager

When after I change dhcp to static in network-scripts and then I restart service`systemctl restart NetworkManager`. The static ip settings suppose to be updated but it doesn't. so I try

`ip link set dev enp0s3 down` and then `up`

didn't update the ip

and then I try with `ifdown enp0s3` then `ifup enp0s3`

it worked

Why has it worked with `ifup`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preamble: `ip` and `ifconfig` are utilities for *controlling* and *monitoring* networking. They are not typically used for reading/writing persistent configuration files - and this is why `ip link` did not work. Persistent configuration management has to be accomplished by other means, such as `NetworkManager`.

(It's likely needless to say, but, as a side note, `iproute2`, which provides `ip`, [has been/is being adopted](https://lwn.net/Articles/710533/) by many distributions as a replacement for `net-tools`, which provides `ifconfig`. They are often both shipped as default packages in distributions for compatibility reasons).

Why `ifup` worked and `systemctl restart NetworkManager` did not:

On CentOS (I have checked for CentOS 7), `ifup` and `ifdown` are provided by `initscripts`; they operate on the scripts in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`, provided by the same package. Thus, no surprise in `ifup` being able to apply the changes you made there.

NetworkManager - the default networking service provider that CentOS inherited from upstream - on Red Hat and Fedora is configured to use [the `ifcfg-rh` plugin](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings-ifcfg-rh.html) to read/write network configuration from `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`. But *it does not monitor* those files.

`man nm-settings-ifcfg-rh` warns that

> Users can create or modify the ifcfg-rh connection files manually, even if that is not the recommended way of managing the profiles. However, if they choose to do that, they must inform NetworkManager about their changes (see monitor-connection-file in nm-settings(5), and nmcli con (re)load).

Thus, `systemctl reload NetworkManager` is not supposed to reload the configuration of a network connection from file on CentOS. To do that you can invoke `nmcli connection reload` or change `NetworkManager` configuration as stated in `man NetworkManager.conf`:

> monitor-connection-files
>   Whether the configured settings plugin(s) should set up file monitors and immediately pick up changes made to connection files while NetworkManager is running. This is disabled by default; NetworkManager will only read the connection files at startup, and when explicitly requested via the ReloadConnections D-Bus call. [...]

Comment: thank you :) how do you check which packages belong to which group package

Comment: Sorry for being late. I'm not an expert here, I would just suggest to start from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257452/which-yum-groups-contain-a-given-package) on StackOverflow. To list packages in a given group: `yum groups info your_group`. To know which group a package belongs to: `yum groups info '*' | less +/your_package` or `yum groupinfo '*' | less +/your_package`.

Answer (score 2):

`ip` directly changes the state of the hardware, just like `ifconfig`. The only difference between `ifconfig` and `ip` is that `ip` has a different syntax, and supports some features `ifconfig` doesn't.

`ifup` and `ifdown`, on the other hand, run a lot of scripts, read your `/etc/network/interfaces` file and other configuration files, and act on that. That includes adding the static IP settings which you probably put into `/etc/network/interfaces`.

In principle, Network Manager should pick up those, too, but I don't run Network Manager (most of the time it gets in my way), so I can't tell you why it didn't work.

So: if you want your network configuration files to be taken into consideration, use `ifup`/`ifdown` and Network Manager. If you want to directly change the interface settings, use `ip` and `ifconfig`.

Comment: Right for debian based distro. For RHEL the network scripts should be under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`